# Scroll to first checked item in a CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I programmatically scroll to the first checked item in a CheckedListBox?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `TopIndex` property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.topindex.aspx

Answer (score 10):

Maybe the [ListBox.TopIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.topindex.aspx) property helps here:

> Gets or sets the index of the first visible item in the ListBox.